# Filling up values of a dict, which in itself is in a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I have a problem. I have a `list` and this in turn contains `dicts`. The problem is that the `dicts` can have different sizes. That some elements are missing in some `dicts`. Is there an option to fill the `dicts` with the missing attributes? It is only a matter of filling up the `keys` and the values can simply be filled up with `None`.

The following example

```py
[
{'_id': 'orders/213123',
 'contactEditor': {'name': 'Max Power',
                   'phone': '1234567'},
 'isCompleteDelivery': False,
},
{'_id': 'orders/2173823',
 'contactEditor': {'name': 'Michael'},
},
]
```

It turns out that the first element has the most `keys` and the second element is missing the following `keys` `phone` and `isCompleteDelivery`.

this is filled in and it looks like this

```py
[
{'_id': 'orders/213123',
 'contactEditor': {'name': 'Max Power',
                   'phone': '1234567'},
 'isCompleteDelivery': False,
},
{'_id': 'orders/2173823',
 'contactEditor': {'name': 'Michael',
                   'phone': None},
 'isCompleteDelivery': None,
},
]
```

This gives me which `dict` has the most elements and the number.

```py
%%time
highest_element = 0
elements = 0
for i, element in enumerate(myList):
    counted = count(myList[i])
    if(counted > elements):
        elements = counted
        highest_element = i
        
print(str(elements) + " " + str(highest_element))
```

```py
myList = [
{'_id': 'orders/213123',
 'contactEditor': {'name': 'Max Power',
  'phone': '1234567',
  'email': 'max@power.com'},
 'contactSoldToParty': {'name': 'Max Not',
  'phone': '123456789',
  'email': 'maxnot@power.com'},
 'isCompleteDelivery': False,
 'metaData': {'dataOriginSystem': 'Goods',
  'dataOriginWasCreatedTime': '10:12:12',},
 'orderDate': '2021-02-22',
 'orderDateBuyer': '2021-02-22',
},
{'_id': 'orders/12323',
 'contactEditor': {'name': 'Max Power2',
  'phone': '1234567',
  'email': 'max@power.com'},
 'contactSoldToParty': {'name': 'Max Not',
  'phone': '123456789',
  'email': 'maxnot@power.com'},
 'isCompleteDelivery': False,
 'metaData': {'dataOriginSystem': 'Goods',
  'dataOriginWasCreatedTime': '10:12:12',},
 },
{'_id': 'orders/12323',
 'contactEditor': {'name': 'Max Power2',
  'phone': '1234567',
  'email': 'max@power.com'},
 'contactSoldToParty': {'name': 'Max Not',
  'phone': '123456789',
  'email': 'maxnot@power.com'},
 'orderDate': '2021-02-22',
 'orderDateBuyer': '2021-02-22',
 },
{'_id': 'orders/12323',
 'contactEditor': {'name': 'Max Power2',
  'phone': '1234567',
  'email': 'max@power.com'},
 'contactSoldToParty': {'name': 'Max Not',},
 'isCompleteDelivery': False,
 },
]
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the `.get` and `.setdefault` methods of dictionaries? If you read the documentation for those, can you see a way to solve the problem? "This gives me which dict has the most elements and the number." Okay, but what if one dictionary is missing one of the possible keys, and a different one is missing a different possible key, and there aren't any dictionaries with all of them?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I haven't heard of that yet. 
And your objection with my strategy is right, it makes sense not to solve it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, it seems that you need to construct a superset of all possible keys. Once you have that you can iterate over the list and set default values in each dictionary. Now that the "top level" dictionaries have been adjusted you need to step down a level and do the same thing for the nested dictionaries. This code is limited to the data structure as shown in the question.

```
list_ = [
    {'_id': 'orders/213123',
     'contactEditor': {'name': 'Max Power',
                       'phone': '1234567'},
     'isCompleteDelivery': False,
     },
    {'_id': 'orders/2173823',
        'contactEditor': {'name': 'Michael'},
     }
]

def modkv(L, K):
    superset_ = set(key for dict_ in list_ for key in dict_[K])
    for dict_ in L:
        for key in superset_:
            dict_[K].setdefault(key, None)

superset = set(key for dict_ in list_ for key in dict_)

for dict_ in list_:
    for key in superset:
        dict_.setdefault(key, None)

for dict_ in list_:
    for k, v in dict_.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            modkv(list_, k)

print(list_)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'_id': 'orders/213123', 'contactEditor': {'name': 'Max Power', 'phone': '1234567'}, 'isCompleteDelivery': False}, {'_id': 'orders/2173823', 'contactEditor': {'name': 'Michael', 'phone': None}, 'isCompleteDelivery': None}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This code make a key if not present in dictionary with the value `None`.

```py
lst = [
{'_id': 'orders/213123',
 'contactEditor': {'name': 'Max Power',
                   'phone': '1234567'},
 'isCompleteDelivery': False,
},
{'_id': 'orders/2173823',
 'contactEditor': {'name': 'Michael'},
},
]

complete_dict = {'_id': None,
 'contactEditor': {'name': None,
                   'phone': None},
 'isCompleteDelivery': None,
} 

# here complete dictionary means which is contain all possible keys.
all_keys = complete_dict.keys() 
for i,value in enumerate(lst):
    for a in all_keys:
        try:
            value[a]
        except KeyError:
            value[a]=None
        else:
            v = value[a]
            if isinstance(v,dict):
                for a2 in complete_dict[a].keys():
                    try:
                        v[a2]
                    except KeyError:
                        v[a2]=None
                value[a]=v

    del lst[i]
    lst.insert(i,value)
print(lst)
```

##### OUTPUT

```py
[{'_id': 'orders/213123',
 'contactEditor': {'name': 'Max Power', 'phone': '1234567'},
 'isCompleteDelivery': False},
 {'_id': 'orders/2173823',
 'contactEditor': {'name': 'Michael', 'phone': None}, 
 'isCompleteDelivery': None}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately the `phone` is missing in your output.

Comment: @Test Sorry for that I didn't notice but don't worry I will change my code in a minute.

Comment: @Test Can I assume that the first dictionary is full?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The first dict may also not contain elements that occur in another dict. As @Karl Knechtel mentioned it.

Comment: @Test So in this case you need to provide a full dictionary here.

Comment: @Test Now I edit my code, I hope this will helps you.